# $.get inside of $.each freezes up

Tags: jquery, loops, freeze, lag, each

```
$('#btnAutoRun').click(function(data){

$('.payment').each(function(index, element) {
    //Looks to see if it shoudld run Credit Card
    if ($('#chkRun',this).is(':checked')) {
        //Gather values to pass in querystring
        strPayment = "cn=" + $(this).attr("cn") + "&amount=" + $(this).attr("minimumDue") + "&mp=" + $(this).attr("minimumDue") + "&sn=" + $(this).attr("sn");
        //calls page that submits information for processing
        $.get("fn_process_payment.asp?" + strPayment + "&desc=Monthly Payment", function(data){
        });
    }
});
    //refreshes payments box
   loadPayments();
```

When I have one checked it runs VERY Quickly. If I have two more checked it bogs the whole system down and I have to pretty much reset the local host.  Is there a better way of accomplishing task or is there a way to force it to wait until the $.get is finished to continue process?

Comment: Just a note, but `$('#chkRun',this)`.  Why are you doing this?  Do you have multiple elements with the id `chkRun`?  Don't do that!  IDs should be unique.

Comment: <div class='.payment'><input type='checkbox' id='chkRun'>client info</div>

Comment: Why do you need an `.each` here at all then?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers typically have a limit to the number of HTTP download processes they'll kick off at once; and most dev versions of IIS - not sure if that's what you're running - also limit the number of requests they'll handle. You may be running into something like that.

That said, there's a way to loop over asynchronous tasks, but it gets a tad complex - the usual technique requires recursion. Something like this:

```
$('#btnAutoRun').click(function(data){

    var $paymentElements = $('.payment');
    processPayment(0);

    function processPayment(idx){
        if (idx >= $paymentElements.length) return;
        if ($('#chkRun',this).is(':checked')) {
            var elm = $paymentElements[idx];
            //Gather values to pass in querystring
            strPayment = "cn=" + $(elm).attr("cn") + 
                "&amount=" + $(elm).attr("minimumDue") + 
                "&mp=" + $(elm).attr("minimumDue") + 
                "&sn=" + $(elm).attr("sn");
            //calls page that submits information for processing
            $.get("fn_process_payment.asp?" + strPayment + "&desc=Monthly Payment", function(data){
                processPayment(idx + 1);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Or something like that - haven't tested it, may be some mistakes in there.

In modern versions of C#, you get to use the `async` and `await` keywords, and that lets you avoid the recursion piece, which is handy. But JS isn't quite there yet.

Comment: Thank You, this worked great. I have this being called on a Button Click so I just had to remove the `var` from $paymentElements.

Comment: You can actually leave the `var` in place if you put the whole thing - including the `function processPayment()` inside the button click handler. See my edit. In fact, that's better, because it keeps the variables all properly scoped.